# PHP doesn´t get expected POST sended by VolleyMultipartRequest [Android]

Tags: php, android, mysql, request, android-volley

When i am sending the Request, the PHP-File return "requiered field(s) missing".

It is because the POST Variable is not received as expected.

Does the VolleyMultipartRequest send the correct byte[] data?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION = 123; //kann jegliche Zahl sein. Wir benutzens halt später

    ImageView imageView;

    RequestQueue queue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);                                                                                                       
    } //...


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){ 

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData(); 

                //working with image
                try {

                    //String path = selectedImage.getPath();

                    Log.i("ImagePath",selectedImage.toString());

                    Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    Log.i("byte", getBitmapData(bitmapImage).toString());

                    sendDataToDB(bitmapImage);




                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


    public void sendDataToDB(final Bitmap bitmap){
        String url = "http://194.145.173.13/android_connect/insert_into_byteArray.php";
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
                Log.i("result", resultResponse);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("api_token", "gh659gjhvdyudo973823tt9gvjf7i6ric75r76");
//              params.put("name", "Angga");
//              params.put("location", "Indonesia");
//              params.put("about", "UI/UX Designer");
//              params.put("contact", "anddgga@email.com");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
                // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
                params.put("byteArray", new DataPart("sample.jpg", getBitmapData(bitmap)));

                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);

    }


}
```

**PHP-File for Insert**

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new user row
 * All user details are read from HTTP Post Request 
 * -> also den POST führt die Android App aus (übergibt Daten) und diese werden hier gelesen
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields (wurden die Felder gesetzt?)
if (isset($_POST['byteArray'])) {

    //In Variablen speichern
    $byteArray = $_POST['byteArray'];

    // include db connect class (php-Datei für Verdbindung einbinden)
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $con = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $query  = "INSERT INTO test(byteArray) VALUES('$byteArray')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con->connect(), $query);

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "byteArray erfolgreich hinzugefügt!";

        // echoing JSON response (JSON File generieren mit ergebnisArray ($response)
        //und zurückgeben an Android-App 
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**VolleyMultipartrequest**

```
/**
 * Custom request to make multipart header and upload file.
 *
 * Sketch Project Studio
 * Created by Angga on 27/04/2016 12.05.
 */
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;

    /**
     * Default constructor with predefined header and post method.
     *
     * @param url           request destination
     * @param headers       predefined custom header
     * @param listener      on success achieved 200 code from request
     * @param errorListener on error http or library timeout
     */
    public VolleyMultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with option method and default header configuration.
     *
     * @param method        method for now accept POST and GET only
     * @param url           request destination
     * @param listener      on success event handler
     * @param errorListener on error event handler
     */
    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Custom method handle data payload.
     *
     * @return Map data part label with data byte
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    /**
     * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param params           string inputs collection
     * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse data into data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
     * @param data             loop through data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write string data into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param parameterName    name of input
     * @param parameterValue   value of input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Write data file into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
     * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
     * @param inputName        name of data input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Simple data container use for passing byte file
     */
    public class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;

        /**
         * Default data part
         */
        public DataPart() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructor with data.
         *
         * @param name label of data
         * @param data byte data
         */
        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor with mime data type.
         *
         * @param name     label of data
         * @param data     byte data
         * @param mimeType mime data like "image/jpeg"
         */
        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data, String mimeType) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
            type = mimeType;
        }

        /**
         * Getter file name.
         *
         * @return file name
         */
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Setter file name.
         *
         * @param fileName string file name
         */
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Getter content.
         *
         * @return byte file data
         */
        public byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        /**
         * Setter content.
         *
         * @param content byte file data
         */
        public void setContent(byte[] content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        /**
         * Getter mime type.
         *
         * @return mime type
         */
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        /**
         * Setter mime type.
         *
         * @param type mime type
         */
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too large content to evaluate... Please be specific...

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I have tried to compress. See my post now.